# Changes in checkbox statut are lost on new entry in a datatable reactive and editable?

Tags: checkbox, shiny, reactive, dt

I am working on a shiny app made for data recording. Each time the observers see a new occurence of an event, a new entry must be recorded. This is translate in the app by adding a line in a reactive and editable dataframe.
When the field work is over, data must be checked for potential entry mistake. Most of the time this is done by another people. Sometimes, data can be interpreted as an error and deleted because out of the box. Yet,I would like to let observers confirmed out of the box data to make sure it is not deleted. To do so i would like a checkbox available in the dataframe.
If i change manually data into the table (text or numeric), changes are saved through the function editable (see code) but if i toggle a checkbox, it is reintialised into untoggled when i add a new entry.
Here an exemple:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Reactive table with checkbox editable"),
  selectInput("photo","Photo", c("choose"="","Dog", "Shovel", "Cat", "Desk")),
  selectInput("description", "Description", c("choose"="","object", "animal")),
  actionButton("add_line", "Add a line"),
  dataTableOutput("table")
),

server <- function(input, output, session) {

# Function to manage cell changes
  
  editable<- function(input,data) {
   observeEvent(input$table_cell_edit, {
      info <- input$table_cell_edit
      row <- info$row
      col <- info$col
      value <- info$value
      
      dat <- data()
      if (col == 3) {  
        dat[row, col] <- as.logical(value) 
      } else {
        dat[row, col] <- value
      }
      data(dat)
      
    })} 
    

# Creating an empty frame
  
  myinitialframe <- data.frame(
    Photo = character(),
    Description = character(),
    Confirmed = character(),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
  
# Get my empty frame reactive
  mydata <- reactiveVal(myinitialframe) 
  
  # ajout de ligne
  observeEvent(input$add_line, {
    new_row <- data.frame(
      Photo = input$photo,
      Description = input$description,
      Confirmed = FALSE
      )
    newdata <- rbind(new_row,mydata())
    mydata(newdata)
  })
  
# Display the table with checkbox in column "Confirmed"

    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    mydata <- as.data.frame (mydata ())
    
    mydata <- datatable(
      mydata,
      editable = "cell",
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(
          list(
            targets = c(3),
            render = JS(
              "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
              "  if (type === 'display') {",
              "    return '<input type=\"checkbox\" ' + (data === 'TRUE' ? 'checked' : '') + '/>';", 
              "  }",
              "  return data;",
              "}"
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
    
})
    editable(input,mydata)


  }
)
```

I have tried :

- shinyInput such as proposed in the forum but haven't been able to make it work when there is new lines to enter as assumed because it is not working with a reactive table?
- Callback and JS :

```
         callback = JS(
        "table.on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {",
        "  var data = table.cell(this).data();",
        "  data = !data;",
        "  table.cell(this).data(data).draw(false);",
        "});"
      ),
```

- 

```
shinyjs::runjs(
      "shinyjs.toggleCheckbox = function(checkbox) {
        var row = checkbox.closest('tr');
        var rowIndex = mytable.row(row).index();
        var newValue = !mytable.cell(rowIndex, 3).data();
        mytable.cell(rowIndex, 3).data(newValue).draw();
      };"
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `server = TRUE` (the default) in `renderDT`, this will be hard. It's easier with `server = FALSE`, and this option allows to use `addRow` to add a new row.

Also, there was an error in your JavaScript code: the R data is converted to JavaScript, so `TRUE` is not the value obtained in JavaScript, this is `true` instead.

Note that I keep a copy of the table in the reactive dataframe `Dat` in case you want to save it for example.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Editable table with checkboxes"),
  selectInput(
    "photo", "Photo", c("choose" = "", "Dog", "Shovel", "Cat", "Desk")
  ),
  selectInput(
    "description", "Description", c("choose" = "", "object", "animal")
  ),
  actionButton("add_line", "Add a new line"),
  DTOutput("table")
)

myinitialframe <- data.frame(
  Photo       = character(),
  Description = character(),
  Confirmed   = logical(),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # we make a reactice dataframe from `myinitialframe`
  Dat <- reactiveVal(myinitialframe)
  
  # but we don't use it in `renderDT` !
  output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      myinitialframe, rownames = TRUE,
      editable = "cell", selection = "none",
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(
          list(
            targets = c(3),
            render = JS(
              "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
              "  if (type === 'display') {",
              "    return '<input type=\"checkbox\" ' + (data ? 'checked' : '') + '/>';", 
              "  }",
              "  return data;",
              "}"
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  # instead we will use a proxy in order to be able to add a new row
  proxy <- dataTableProxy("table")
  
  # we use`editData` to update the reactive table
  observeEvent(input[["table_cell_edit"]], {
    info <- input[["table_cell_edit"]]
    dat <- Dat()
    new_dat <- editData(dat, info, rownames = TRUE)
    Dat(new_dat)
  })
  
  # now we handle the adding line feature
  #  with the help of the `addRow` function
  observeEvent(input[["add_line"]], {
    new_row <- data.frame(
      Photo       = input[["photo"]],
      Description = input[["description"]],
      Confirmed   = FALSE
    )
    new_dat <- rbind(Dat(), new_row)
    Dat(new_dat)
    rownames(new_row) <- nrow(new_dat)
    addRow(proxy, new_row, resetPaging = FALSE)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

## Edit: update the 'Confirmed' column

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Editable table with checkboxes"),
  selectInput(
    "photo", "Photo", c("choose" = "", "Dog", "Shovel", "Cat", "Desk")
  ),
  selectInput(
    "description", "Description", c("choose" = "", "object", "animal")
  ),
  actionButton("add_line", "Add a new line"),
  DTOutput("table")
)

myinitialframe <- data.frame(
  Photo       = character(),
  Description = character(),
  Confirmed   = integer(),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


callback <- JS(
  "table.on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {",
  "  var $this = $(this);",
  "  var row = parseInt($this.attr('name')) + 1;",
  "  var bit = $this.prop('checked') ? 1 : 0;",
  "  var info = [{row: row, col: 3, value: bit}];",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('table_cell_edit:DT.cellInfo', info);",
  "});"
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # we make a reactice dataframe from `imynitialframe`
  Dat <- reactiveVal(myinitialframe)
  
  # but we don't use in `renderDT` !
  output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      myinitialframe, rownames = TRUE,
      editable = "cell", selection = "none",
      callback = callback,
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(
          list(
            targets = c(3),
            render = JS(
              "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
              "  if (type === 'display') {",
              "    return `<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"${meta.row}\"' + (data ? 'checked' : '') + '/>`;", 
              "  }",
              "  return data;",
              "}"
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  # instead we will use a proxy in order to be able to add a new row
  proxy <- dataTableProxy("table")
  
  # we use`editData` to update the reactive table
  observeEvent(input[["table_cell_edit"]], {
    info <- input[["table_cell_edit"]]
    print(info)
    dat <- Dat()
    new_dat <- editData(dat, info, rownames = TRUE)
    Dat(new_dat)
  })
  
  # now we handle the adding line feature
  #  with the help of the `addRow` function
  observeEvent(input[["add_line"]], {
    new_row <- data.frame(
      Photo       = input[["photo"]],
      Description = input[["description"]],
      Confirmed   = 0L
    )
    new_dat <- rbind(Dat(), new_row)
    Dat(new_dat)
    rownames(new_row) <- nrow(new_dat)
    addRow(proxy, new_row, resetPaging = FALSE)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, the code using a proxy table is working for the display. The datatable displayed in the panel keep the checkbox checked when new rows are added. But Dat() is not updated and i want to save a .csv of the dataframe with the new inputs and edits. I can't find out how to save the changes. I have tried two possibilities either directly in a .csv from de proxy table (write_csv2(proxy$x$data, file = path) but it didn't work. Or modify the Dat() based on the proxy to save it after (observe({DT::replaceData(proxy,Dat or Dat() or Dat$data)}) but it didn't work either.

Comment: @tomB Strange, `Dat()` *is* updated by my code.

Comment: Sorry, i think i haven't been clear enough in the comment above. I created a save button which transform the Dat() into a .csv. All changes are updated when i modify the text. Example: i change an entry "Dog" into "Cat" directly on the display table and its works, Dat() is updated. But when i check a box on the displayed table, the statut of the check box stay on FALSE when saving the Dat(). When you said Dat() is updated does it mean the check box as well? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @tomB Ah no.... does not look easy to do. Let me think about.

Comment: @tomB See my edit. It works, but I had to replace TRUE/FALSE with 1/0.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works fine with the exemple i used to explain the problem. Now i will try to apply it to my app which is a bit more complex.